# Need clarification in Dropbox sample application

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox

I need to integrate DropBox in my application. I tried dropbox sample application downloaded from www.dropbox.com. While working with that app after Login to dropbox, it goes to Random photo controller and there when we press the Random Photo Button, it is showing the Alert that **"Put .jpg photos in your Photos folder to use DBRoulette!**. But in dropbox website, there are three .jpg images.

Comment: check whether the app accessType RootFolder or FullFolder

Answer (score 0):

Check your dropbox folders ... you will have a new one called Apps. One of the subfolders will be your apps root folder. Place a photo there with jpg or jpeg extension and it should work.